# How Do I Ask the User for An Input Indefinitely Without Using Any Loops?

Tags: java

I'm not allowed to use any loops in my assignments lately, which has me stumped on this latest assignment. I'm supposed to ask the user for a series of integers, indefinitely, until they enter a non-integer, then inform them of the greatest integer. This following code, however, only takes in a single input:

```
public class GreatestNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        int g=0;
        System.out.println("Enter several numbers. Enter a non-integer to end.");
        if(in.hasNext()){
        try{a=in.nextInt();
        g=Greatest(a); }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Greatest number in that sequence is "+g);
        }}}
    public static int Greatest(int x){
        int g=0;
        if (x>g){
            g=x;
        }
        return g;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Recursion or [Stream.generate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) seem to be the two options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of code. You could use recursion. Define **`greatest`** as taking a `Scanner`, check for an `int` and recurse with `Math.max(int, int)`. Like,

```
public static int greatest(Scanner in) {
    if (in.hasNextInt()) {
        return Math.max(in.nextInt(), greatest(in));
    }
    return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

Then to call it, you only need something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter several numbers. Enter a non-integer to end.");
    System.out.println("Greatest number in that sequence is " + greatest(in));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly as intended, thanks!